# Cannot connect Ubuntu to Windows pc either direction

Tags: windows, connection

New to Ubuntu and really struggling with this. I want to connect to my old windows XP PC on our home network. Searching for solutions gets complicated as at one level you are told use

Connect to Server. I set to Windows Share, type in server IP address..

... I get "Failed to retrieve share list from server"

Demo on Youtube worked with no problem.

Other advice in ask Ubuntu is you need to install samba. Did that but nothing seems to happen when I try and run it other than it asking for admin password. (How do you tell what is running on Ubuntu?)

So I try the other direction Windows XP to Ubuntu. I made the Ubuntu directory within home frank shared and tried various combination such as \ipaddress\home\frank but just "The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Please choose another."
My entire data only drive is shared in Windows and no problems accessing that from other Win XP boxes on our network

There are no alerts in Windows firewall, Ubuntu Firestarter did block but changed that to allowed... or so I thought.

In firestarter I had set up Inbound traffic policy 192.168.1.1/24. And since then it has added the ip address of the win pc twice.

So, I am in a state of confusion not knowing where to turn next so thought Ask Ubuntu :)

Comment: you can always check if your samba por is listening: type in the terminal `netstat -nat | grep 445`

Comment: Well all went well the other day, but now it is refusing to accept my password... how can I set things up so I do not need a password at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, turn off Firestarter while you troubleshoot this. It will only complicate any problems, and you won't know if they are caused by a samba misconfiguration or Firestarter. Once you get the connection working, you can re-enable Firestarter.

Check out these Samba Troubleshooting links:

- http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/diagnosis.html
- http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch09_01.html

Samba uses smb.conf for its configuration. Here is a portion of my smb.conf where I create a share called "shared" that I access from both Win XP and Win 7.

```
[shared]
    comment = My Shared Partition
    path = /mnt/shared/
    browseable = yes
    available = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    valid users = my_windows_account_name
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. So would my path be /home/frank ?

Comment: I tried editing that file but it does not allow me to. Tried changing permissions, it does not allow that says I am not the owner. Help not helpful as not a word about if you are not the owner of your own files!!! Huh?

Why is Samba needed and not just the Connect to Server?

Comment: Changed owner to my user by using Press ALT+F2 and type gksu nautilus. Now I can edit it but when I come to save I get an alert saying it could not make a backup copy, with option to save anyway... did not work.. so changed ownership of Samba folder to me and finally got is saved

Comment: I ran Samba again. Entered password. Should something display after that?

Comment: The path (/mnt/shared in my example) is the folder to be shared. When you connect to \\computername\shared from another computer, you are actually connecting to /mnt/shared.  What command did you use to "run samba again?"

Comment: Anyway now tried connecting from Win XP and it has found the Ubuntu box :)  but when I try to enter password it is not accepting :(  also it has created a new workgroup so will have to do it again to try and get it in right workgroup

Comment: Your workgroup can be configured in smb.conf. Also, the login for the user connecting via samba is defined with smbpasswd, and it is not synced with the Ubuntu password.

Comment: SAMBA Diagnotics... fell down on test 1. I cannot work out how to run command IN the SAMBA directory

Comment: To run samba I click on smybol icon at top - type in samba - then click on it - prompts for password. Nothing else happens but I guess it has done whatever it is supposed to?

Comment: I found the workgroup setting and changed that. Password - OK will see if I can find that setting... presume in same config file

Comment: That is unclear, I see  unix password sync = yes but the rest is beyond me... this all seems terribly complicated!

Comment: smbpasswd is a console command, not a setting in smb.conf. Also, the troubleshooting links that I gave show how to use the smbclient command to troubleshoot connections.

Comment: OK thanks. Not sure if password change worked as I got a message Could not connect to machine 127.0.0.1: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE - will go relook at yuour links

Comment: 127.0.0.1 means the local computer.

Comment: Raised that as a separate question as apparently it means I need old password... and that is turning into another long story

Comment: Password proved to be the key, needed to put sudo in front of command. Thanks for the rest of above help Tom which got everything else resolved.